# Issue with TimeStamp value in XML

Tags: xml, timestamp, jmeter

Is there a possibility to change the timestamp in XML, generated by the view result in table while writing to a file from milliseconds (Unix format) to a standard Windows date format?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-box you can change timestamp output format only for CSV output (saving "View Results in Table" in csv in instead of xml).
The XML format does not currently support anything but milliseconds.

If CSV instead of XML in this case is acceptable you can simply set 1 property in jmeter.properties (%JMETER_HOME%/bin/jmeter.properties):

```
# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

or, for non-GUI mode, provide the same as command-line option:

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

If you nevertheless need XML you possibly have to process generated jtl/xml using any script to convert all the unix-like timestamps into desired format.
E.g., for GMT time:

```
=(((X)/1000+((365*70+17)*86400))/86400)+2
```

Look also into [this article](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/LogAnalysis) for details and possible recipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with Excel, created a new column to do a timestamp conversion from Unix to Excel and set the format as date `aaaa-mm-gg h:mm;@` each time, as suggested above by another answer.

Or open it with a text editor which supports python scripting and then create a python script to convert all timestamps.

I used Notepad++ with Python Script plugin.
Then in `Plugin -> Python Script -> New Script` I created the following script:

```
import datetime
import math
import re


# Define a method which uses Epoch converter (Unix timestamp, counted in seconds, not milliseconds)
# to convert milliseconds timestamp into human readable format
def my_replace(match):
    result = match.group().replace("\"", "") # remove quotes
    timestamp = math.floor(int(result) / 1000) # remove millis
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    timestamp = str(timestamp) + "." + result[-3:] # add millis
    return "\"" + timestamp + "\"" # put quotes back


# First we'll start an undo action, then Ctrl-Z will undo the actions of the whole script
editor.beginUndoAction()


# retrieve possible Unix timestamps in milliseconds
# they have to be between quotes and in range between
# from Sunday 09/09/2001 01:46:40.000 ("1000000000000")
# to   Friday 11/06/2128 08:53:19.999 ("4999999999999")
# then it converts to readable dates format
editor.rereplace(r'\"[1-4]\d{12}\"', my_replace)


# End the undo action, so Ctrl-Z will undo the above two actions
editor.endUndoAction()
```

(Note that `editor` is a dedicated instance used by Python Script to define Notepad++ source, so if you create your script into a different editor, you'll have to figure how it identifies the source in its Phython Scripts tool.)

Then I saved the script as `TimestampToDate.py` where suggested by the Plugin.
After I can use `Plugin -> Python Script -> Scripts -> TimestampToDate` to replace all  those xml timestamps to readable dates, each time.
It also automatically adds your local timezone, by Python default.

If you prefer to read it with a text editor, instead than Excel, this is a longer method for the very first time, but once you saved the script, it's just a metter to execute it each time from the menu.